# How to use pre-built word embedding in tfLearn?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tflearn

I would like to build recurrent neural net binary classifier in tfLearn. But I want to use my pre-built word embedding, which I have saved in the pickle. Following is the tflearn code I am using in the model.

```
# Network building
net = tflearn.input_data([None, 100])
net = tflearn.embedding(net, input_dim=10000, output_dim=128) ##Have to change this##
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128, dropout=0.8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.001,
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

How can I use my pre-built word embedding in this model (line 2)?